# What is the minimum setup to post an Ad using Facebook Marketing API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

We need to integrate with Facebook Marketing API for a simple workflow. A user should be able to login to the app with Facebook and allow us to post ads on their behalf.

It seems simple, however we are hitting a strange bug while creating an AdSet. While performing a correct call:

```
  curl -i -X POST \
   "https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/act_XXX/adsets/?status=PAUSED&optimization_goal=REACH&daily_budget=10&name=Test%20Ad%20Set&campaign_id=XXX&targeting=%7B%22geo_locations%22%3A%7B%22countries%22%3A%5B%22US%22%5D%7D%7D&end_time=2015-03-12%2023%3A59%3A59-07%3A00&access_token=<access token sanitized>"
```

With token permissions:

```
  {
    "perms": [
      "ads_management",
      "ads_read",
      "public_profile"
    ],
    "user_id": XXX,
    "app_id": XXX
  }
```

and with POST payload:

```
  {
    "status": "PAUSED",
    "optimization_goal": "REACH",
    "daily_budget": "10",
    "name": "Test Ad Set",
    "campaign_id": "XXX",
    "targeting": "{\"geo_locations\":{\"countries\":[\"US\"]}}",
    "end_time": "2015-03-12 23:59:59-07:00"
  }
```

We get a response reading:

```
  {
    "error": {
      "message": "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "is_transient": true,
      "code": 2,
      "fbtrace_id": "AUV0_CHdqPNtGuqNd-ZHCW6"
    }
  }
```

This seems like a bug on FB side, however, they seem have a track record of returning this message when something is wrong with a request or permissions. While we are waiting for their support response, I am wondering if something could be wrong on our side.

The app is pretty bare bone right now, and we are playing only with the Graph Explorer tokens. Should we go through some review process to get rid of the error? Posting ad campaigns works correctly, so this is even stranger.